# Having empty columns/rows in pandas.DataFrames being displayed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which look like this:

```
df = pandas.dataframe()
df.set_value(1,9,"AA1")
...
df.set_value(3,14,"FF3")
print(df)

             9            10           11           13           14
1           AA1          BB1          CC1          DD1          FF1
2           AA2          BB2          CC2          DD2          FF2
3           AA3          BB3          CC3          DD3          FF3
```

For an other program I need to output it with columns 1 to 8 and 12, which are empty.

Is there a way to do without `df.set_value(1,1,None)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no columns befor column `9`, so impossible display it.

```
print (df.columns)
Int64Index([9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], dtype='int64')
```

So need add them - e.g. by [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
df = df.reindex_axis(range(df.columns.max() + 1), axis=1)
print (df)
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11  12   13   14
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  AA1  BB1  CC1 NaN  DD1  FF1
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  AA2  BB2  CC2 NaN  DD2  FF2
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  AA3  BB3  CC3 NaN  DD3  FF3
```

---

```
df = df.reindex_axis(range(1, df.columns.max() + 1), axis=1)
print (df)
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9    10   11  12   13   14
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  AA1  BB1  CC1 NaN  DD1  FF1
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  AA2  BB2  CC2 NaN  DD2  FF2
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  AA3  BB3  CC3 NaN  DD3  FF3
```